# Unable to alter foreign column from nullable to not null in Laravel 5.8 migration

Tags: laravel

I have a table with `unit_id`, `building_id` and `property_id` as nullable. Now, I want to update it to not null. However, the migration is returning following error:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1832 Cannot change column 'building_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'amenity_pricing_reviews_building_id_foreign' (SQL: ALTER TABLE
 amenity_pricing_reviews CHANGE unit_id unit_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, CHANGE building_id building_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, CHANGE property_id property_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, CHANGE dom dom VARCHAR(191) CHA
RACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`)
```

And my schema looks like:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('amenity_pricing_reviews', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->dropForeign(['unit_id','building_id','property_id']);
            $table->unsignedInteger('unit_id')->nullable(false)->change();
            $table->unsignedInteger('building_id')->nullable(false)->change();
            $table->unsignedInteger('property_id')->nullable(false)->change();
            $table->foreign('unit_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('units');
            $table->foreign('building_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('buildings')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('property_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('properties')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('dom')->nullable()->change();
        });
    }
```

This is how I had created these columns on first time:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('unit_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('unit_id')->references('id')->on('units')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->unsignedInteger('building_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('building_id')->references('id')->on('buildings')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->unsignedInteger('property_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('property_id')->references('id')->on('properties')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: remove this and try again `$table->dropForeign(['unit_id','building_id','property_id']);`

Comment: @xNoJustice same issue

Comment: Get same error? @Aayus Dahal

Comment: @xNoJustice yes

Comment: Use `unsignedBigInteger` and `php artisan migration --force` take backup before

Comment: I have updated the question by adding how I added on first time. I don't think `unsignedBigInteger` is the issue, because I had created as just `unsignedInteger` at first

Answer (score 1):

Try to set foreign key check to zero in your migration file then run your migration

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
```